# How to limit memory used by Java JVM by Tomcat7?

Tags: memory, tomcat7, virtual-machine

I'm using tomcat7 for my application server with this configuration of JAVA_OPS:

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server -Xms1024m -Xmx4096M
-XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=512m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m 
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

This Tomcat is running on Ubuntu 14.04. Server RAM is 8GB. What is de problem that application is slowly gaining more and more memory. Is not stopping on desired 4GB. Is going up, over 95% memory is used (Server is up ~2 days) and than tomcat is frozen.

Am I doing something wrong in my configuration? Any ideas?